# How can I edit this in order for it to execute properly?

Tags: sas

I encounter an error with this SAS code.  The error says there is no class listed.

```html
data jobs;
infile 'Documents\pay_survey.txt';
input gender pay;
run;

proc ttest data=jobs;
class gender;
var pay;
run;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the error you are getting? Please click edit and add this information. Don't add as a comment.

Comment: Thank you @Mozahler I've edited the original post and added this information.

Comment: does your jobs table has data for gender. looks like you have mentioned as numeric variable. I feel that there might be problems with jobs table  itself

Comment: Please post the text from the SAS log with the error message.  Your posted code looks fine. But perhaps is not correct for your actual data. Can you also post a couple of lines of the text file you are reading?

Comment: Male    Senior     16.82
Female  Freshman     3.5

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some common pieces of an `infile` data step. Usually you want something that looks like:

```
data jobs;
  infile 'Documents\pay_survey.txt' dlm=',';
  informat gender $1. pay best12.;
  input gender pay;
run;
```

The `dlm=` option specifies the delimiter in your data if it is something other than a space (your code should work fine if your data is space-delimited). The `informat` statement tells SAS how to read the data since it can't know on its own how it should interpret the text file.

If this doesn't help, try providing more detail on your input data (provide a sample) so we can give you something that should work for sure.

Comment: ERROR: All observations are missing a CLASS value.

Comment: The results showed the TTest Table but all values were missing and had a '-' instead.